# Problem on overlay on top of a MPMoviePlauerViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayer

I have a movie player view controller which i want to add a overlay view on top of it.

I used the following code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
      // Custom initialization
      [[moviePlayer view] addSubview:[self overlayControlsView]];

      UIGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
      [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tap];
  }
  return self;
}
```

overlayControlsView is currently only a UILabel.

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Tap handled");
    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if ([[self overlayControlsView] isHidden]) {
            [[self overlayControlsView] setHidden:NO];
        } else {
            [[self overlayControlsView] setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

When the movieplayer is just displayed, tapping on it causes the overlayControlsView shows and hides successfully.

However, right after the moviewplayer load state changed and starts to play (I load the video from the Internet, and so there's some time gap here), the handleTap method was not called anymore.

Does anyone has any idea on it? Is there a better way to add overlay controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know whats wrong with your code; here is an alternative of accomplishing overlay control using custom button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample-video" ofType:@"mov"];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString]];
    UIButton *overlayView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [overlayView setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [overlayView setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [overlayView addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 250);
    overlayView.frame = player.view.frame;
    [player.view addSubview:overlayView];
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
     }


- (void)handleTap:(id *)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (btn.selected) {
        [player play];
        [btn setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {
        [player pause];
        [btn setSelected:YES];
    } }
```

Comment: Sorry that may be I describe wrong. But what I would like to do is to show / hide the overlay view when I tap on the player (think of the default controls, with my custom overlay view, so that they would fade in / out together with the default controls). Yours is having a button on top, and clicking it would play / pause the video, which is not what I want.

Comment: @PeterWong, play/pause was just an example of showing overlay control,  I think you can use the same for show/hide overlay view... I too had the same problem of using UIGestureRecognizer over MPMoviePlayerController view.. and opted this way.

Comment: So it would be a invisible button op top of the whole player waiting for tapping? That's seems great. Will have a try tomorrow.